# Firebase auth check if it's first login

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am building an iOS app and using firebase for it.
So I've got a few questions.

Here's my code snippet.

```
const metadata = auth.currentUser.metadata;
if (metadata.creationTime === metadata.lastSignInTime) {
    //this means it is a new user

    navigation.navigate('Welcome');
} else {
    // this means the user is existing already

    let lastSignInDate, currentDate;
    const lastSignInTimeUTCLocal = new Date(auth.currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime);
    lastSignInDate = lastSignInTimeUTCLocal.getDate().toString();
    currentDate = new Date().getDate().toString();
    if (lastSignInDate === currentDate) {
      navigation.navigate('MainScreen');
    } else {
      navigation.navigate('Greeting');
    }
}
```

So what I am going to implement here is

If new user, show welcome screen

If not, show a greetings once per day and after that, main page.

So for the 2nd login in the same day, it doesn't show a greetings and just redirect to main page.

I use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to login.
But I noticed that this changes `lastSignInTime` of metadata so it always redirect to main page.

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to implement this with Firebase Authentication alone.  You will need to record some information about the user's sign-in behaviors in a database or some other persistent storage, and query that to determine what to display based on their prior behavior.

Comment: What do you think if I save it to firebase realtime DB?

Comment: You could certainly do that.